# How can I catch a rendering error / missing template in node.js using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have code like this that will render a jade template without a route defined. Think of this like the express.static but it calls res.render with the url.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        res.render(req.url.substring(1), { title: "No Controller", user: req.session.user });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        next();
    }
});
```

The problem is that res.render() isn't throwing an error. Instead it is rendering an error page. Is there a way to detect a missing template or any rendering errors?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A better way to do it, instead of requiring `fs` and having another callback, would be to use render's callback :

```
res.render(my_page_im_not_sure_it_exists, {}, function(err, html) {
    if(err) {
        res.redirect('/404'); // File doesn't exist
    } else {
        res.send(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great find. Its only in 3.x docs but it works in 2.x as well.

Comment: Updated answer to use `res.send` instead of `res.end`. 4.x documentation [specifically states](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.end) "If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as res.send()"

Comment: I thought this would generate a 404 if there was an error processing the template, but it doesn't seem to. Anyone care to explain why it does not?

Comment: A `404` code is what **your server** wants to reply to a request to tell the querying browser [conventionnaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) that the page was not found. At this step, you **are** the server, and you are free to reply with whatever you want. If you want to send a 404 error instead of redirecting the the `/404` url, the correct way to do this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393275/how-to-programmatically-send-a-404-response-with-express-node).

Comment: What does the second argument in 'render' indicate? I am talking about the "{}" after "my_page_im_not_sure_it_exists"

Comment: Options I guess. Unable to tell you which without the docs though.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen its for options to pass some data variables to the rendered template

Answer (score 2):

Use `fs.exists(p, [callback])` to check if the file exists before calling `res.render`

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback

**Node 0.6.x and older**

Use `path.exists(p, [callback])` to check if the file exists before calling `res.render`

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.0/api/path.html#path.exists

Comment: With the latest (0.8.x) version of node, you should use `fs.exists()`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Augustin Riedinger's answer, the same applies when rendering to variable using [`renderFile`](http://jade-lang.com/api/):

```
var html = jade.renderFile('path/to/file.jade', context, function(err, html) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fs.open` to check if the template exists.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    fs.open(__dirname + '/views/' + req.url.substring(1) + '.jade', 'r', function (err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next();
      }
      res.render(req.url.substring(1), { title: "No Controller", user: req.session.user });
    }
});
```

Comment: res.render has a bunch of logic for figuring out what jade file to use. I was hoping that I wouldn't need to recreate that logic.