# How to programmatically send a 404 response with Express/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-codes

I want to simulate a 404 error on my Express/Node server. How can I do that?

Comment: How would "simulated" differ from a "real" one?

Answer (score 344, accepted):

Since Express 4.0, there's a dedicated [`sendStatus` function](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendStatus):

```js
res.sendStatus(404);
```

---

If you're using an earlier version of Express, use the [`status` function](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status) instead.

```js
res.status(404).send('Not found');
```

Comment: This also works with rendered pages: `res.status(404).render('error404')`

Comment: Worth noting that on it's own `res.status(404);` wont send a response AFAIK.  It needs to either be chained with something, e.g. `res.status(404).end();` or your second example, or it needs to be followed by e.g. `res.end();`, `res.send('Not found');`

Comment: @UpTheCreek, I'll remove the first example from the code to avoid the potential for that confusion.

Comment: shorter version `res.sendStatus(404)`

Comment: @bentesha plan and simple.

Answer (score 56):

### Updated Answer for Express 4.x

Rather than using `res.send(404)` as in old versions of Express, the new method is:

```
res.sendStatus(404);
```

Express will send a very basic 404 response with "Not Found" text:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9
ETag: W/"9-nR6tc+Z4+i9RpwqTOwvwFw"
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 20:08:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Not Found
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just `res.status(404)` not `res.sendStatus(404)`.

Comment: `res.sendStatus(404)` is correct.  It is equivalent to `res.status(404).send()`

Comment: Yep `res.sendStatus(404); ` is equivalent to  `res.status(404).send('Not Found')`

Comment: @JakeWilson now what is it ??

Answer (score 44):

You don't have to simulate it. The second argument to `res.send` I believe is the status code. Just pass 404 to that argument.

Let me clarify that: Per [the documentation on expressjs.org](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) it seems as though any number passed to `res.send()` will be interpreted as the status code. So technically you could get away with:

```
res.send(404);
```

*Edit:* My bad, I meant `res` instead of `req`. It should be called on the response

*Edit:* As of Express 4, the `send(status)` method has been deprecated. If you're using Express 4 or later, use: `res.sendStatus(404)` instead. (Thanks @badcc for the tip in the comments)

Comment: You could also send a message with the 404:
    `res.send(404, "Could not find ID "+id)`

Comment: Sending a status code directly is deprecated in 4.x and will probably be removed at some point. Best to stick with `.status(404).send('Not found')`

Comment: For Express 4: "express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead"

Answer (score 10):

According to the site I'll post below, it's all how you set up your server. One example they show is this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    route(handle, pathname, response);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

and their route function:

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
  if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
    handle[pathname](response);
  } else {
    console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("404 Not found");
    response.end();
  }
}

exports.route = route;
```

This is one way.
http://www.nodebeginner.org/

From another site, they create a page and then load it. This might be more of what you're looking for.

```
fs.readFile('www/404.html', function(error2, data) {
            response.writeHead(404, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
            response.end(data);
        });
```

http://blog.poweredbyalt.net/?p=81

Answer (score 10):

From the [Express site](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), define a NotFound exception and throw it whenever you want to have a 404 page OR redirect to /404 in the below case:

```
function NotFound(msg){
  this.name = 'NotFound';
  Error.call(this, msg);
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee);
}

NotFound.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

app.get('/404', function(req, res){
  throw new NotFound;
});

app.get('/500', function(req, res){
  throw new Error('keyboard cat!');
});
```

Comment: This example code is no longer at the link you reference. Might this apply to an earlier version of express?

Comment: It actually stil applies to the existing code, all you have to do is to use the error handle middleware to catch the error. Ex: `app.use(function(err, res, res, next) { if (err.message.indexOf('NotFound') !== -1) { res.status(400).send('Not found dude'); }; /* else .. etc */ });`

Answer (score 4):

IMO the nicest way is to use the `next()` function:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not found');
    err.status = 404;
    return next(err);
}
```

Then the error is handled by your error handler and you can style the error nicely using HTML.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, in a node/express context using the middleware is far more consistent.