# Handle 404 Error with resource

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have the following Middleware to protect my get-route.

```
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user.role == "admin") {
        return next();
    }
    return res.send(404);
}
```

Is the way I send the error correct?

And this is my API call:

```
$scope.users = APIService.query({ route:'users' });
```

How, can I catch the 404 and do some stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

...so, there's a ton of stuff out there that turns up on search engines.

That said, try this as a quick fix that points in one direction you can take:

```
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user.role == "admin") {
        return next();
    }
    res.status(404).send('You need to be admin to see this page');
}
```

There's good stuff on handling 404's at:

- [The official Express docs on `res.status`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status)
- [How to programmatically send a 404 response with Express/Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393275/how-to-programmatically-send-a-404-response-with-express-node)
- [error handling examples from the express github page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js)

The last one also provides examples on handling the error while rendering a template.

Comment: Thank you! And how I can handle the error in angular, in my query?

Comment: Dunno.  I'm a newbie at Angular but I know enough that you should probably ask a new question about that. because there are a few ways you could be handling the async calls from Angular to node, you should post the code from your angular app in the new question.  That will get you the best chances of getting an answer to your second question.

Comment: Is the order of middlewares important? For exmaple when i use a middleware to redirect 404 errors. Must they stand at the end? For example: app.get('/api/users', isLoggedIn, isAdmin, isError function(req, res) and what is there position when i place the middleware in app.use? thank you!

Comment: Yes.  Middleware will execute in the order it is listed.  When you see `(req, res, next)`, calling `next()` tells express to move to the next middleware component in the stack if a response was not sent. This is a reason that some middleware (loggers, parsers, etc) need to be 'at the top' of the app so that they pre-process information before routes/business logic get processes.