# How to mock response from http.request (nodejs, jasmine, sinon)

Tags: node.js, http, mocking, jasmine, sinon

I've written a small `node` module that makes a `http` request and I am having trouble testing it.
The code in question looks like this:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    var http = require("http"),
        Promise = require("promise");

    var send = function send(requestOptions, requestBody) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            http.request(requestOptions, function (response) {
                var responseChunks = [];

                response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    responseChunks.push(chunk);
                });

                response.on('end', function () {
                    resolve(Buffer.concat(responseChunks));
                });

                response.on('error', function (e) {
                    reject(e);
                });
            }).end(requestBody);
        });
    };

    return {
        send: send
    }
```

and I am trying to test my `send` method, in particular the callback function that is invoked by `http.request`.
I *think* what I need to do is to mock or stub the `response` object from `http.request` so that I can then test the execution of the callback function. But I can't figure out how to do that.

If it's of any relevance I am using `node` v4.1, `jasmine` v2.3, and `sinon` v1.17

Answer (score 3):

Instead of stubbing, you can try creating a local or "mock" server that responds to your requests. This avoids having to stub out http.request. One of the benefits of a local server is this method should work whether you are using http.request, XMLHttpRequest, or a similar method to grab an online resource.

## Mock Server

You can try [mock server](http://www.mock-server.com/). With it, you can create a fake server to fulfill your requests.

### Installing

```
npm install mockserver-grunt --save-dev
npm install mockserver-client --save-dev
```

### Jasmine Code

In your Spec (or test), you can use the following (change to suit your needs):

```
var mockServer = require("mockserver-grunt");
var mockServerClient = require("mockserver-client").mockServerClient;

beforeAll(function(done) {
  // start the server
  mockServer.start_mockserver({
    serverPort: 1080,
    verbose: true
  });

  // setup how to respond
  let response = {name:'value'};
  let statusCode = 203;
  mockServerClient("localhost", 1080).mockSimpleResponse('/samplePath', response, statusCode);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // give time for the mock server to setup
    done();
  }, 4000);
});

it("should be able to GET an online resource", function(done) {
   // perform tests, send requests to http://localhost:1080/samplePath
}
```

This will start the server on port 1080. Any requests made to http://localhost:1080/samplePath will receive the provided response.

In a similar manner, the server can be shutdown at the end of your test:

```
afterAll(function() {
  mockServer.stop_mockserver({
    serverPort: 1080,
    verbose: true
  });
});
```

### Other Notes

#### Fixing a corrupt jar file

When the server is first started, it will attempt to download a jar file required for the server. This is a one time download (as far as I know). If it is not provided enough time, it will not fully download, and you will end up with an invalid or corrupt jar file. To correct this, you can download the jar file yourself. The link is provided in the run. For me, this was located at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mock-server/mockserver-netty/3.10.6/mockserver-netty-3.10.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Most likely, you will want to navigate to the latest version.

---

## Update

## Express JS Server

Since I originally posted, I found Express JS. Express starts a server instance much faster than Mock Server. You also do not have to worry about a jar file.

### Installing

```
npm install express --save-dev
```

### Jasmine Code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var server;

beforeAll(function() {
  server = app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on port " + port);
  });

  app.get('/samplePath', function (req, res) {
    res.send("my response");
  });

});

afterAll(function() {
  // shutdown
  server.close();
});

it("should be able to GET an online resource", function(done) {
   // perform tests, send requests to http://localhost:3000/samplePath
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can return the path that you use. For example, if you go to http://localhost:3000/helloworld, the return value will be helloworld. You can adapt this to suit your needs.

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params[0]);
});
```

If you need to force the code down an error path, you can use

```
res.status(404)        // HTTP status 404: NotFound
 .send('Not found');
```

Source: [How to programmatically send a 404 response with Express/Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393275/how-to-programmatically-send-a-404-response-with-express-node)

---

### Configuring Express JS with HTTPS

Express JS can be configured to use HTTPS. With openssl, a self-signed certificate can be created using:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Source: [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Update the express js code with the following to use HTTPS.

```
const secureOptions = {
   key: fs.readFileSync("./spec/ExpressServer/key.pem"),
   cert: fs.readFileSync("./spec/ExpressServer/cert.pem")
};

var secureServer = https.createServer(secureOptions, app);
```

Note: You may have to configure the security of your applications to allow a self-signed certificate for HTTPS.

Comment: Nice idea, as it involves sending real http requests. As it happens, since posting the original question, I am using mockserver in a number of java projects, so am very familiar with the project. Nice :)

Comment: This is a great idea but its usefulness may be limited depending on the https encryption configuration: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-tls

Comment: Great! It helped me in sending a nested request to an API. The case was that I was calling an API for integration test and that API calls another API inside. I need to mock that nested API to test my API. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock). It is great for mocking http request in test cases.

Answer (score 0):

The mocha testing frame work and Should.JS (assertion lib) is pretty nice.

See the getting started section: https://mochajs.org/

Essentially, you use the `mocha` framework to create test cases. Then you use the `should.js` node module to make assertions (facts about what should happen).

You can install it via `npm install mocha` & `npm install should`

#### Mocha Test File Code:

```
module.exports.run =  function() {
    var chalk = require('chalk');
    var should = require('should');
    var http = require("http");

    describe('test lib description', function(done){
      it('Individual Test Case description', function(done) {
        function send(requestOptions, requestBody) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                http.request(requestOptions, function (response) {
                    var responseChunks = [];

               // Assertions using Should.JS
               // Example: The http status code from the server should be 200

                    should.equal(response.statusCode , 200);
                    response.should.have.property('someProperty');
                    response.should.have.property('someProperty','someVal');

                    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                         responseChunks.push(chunk);
                         done(); // Needed To tell mocha we are ready to move on to next test
                    });

                    response.on('end', function () {
                        resolve(Buffer.concat(responseChunks));
                        done();
                    });

                    response.on('error', function (e) {
                        reject(e);
                        done();
                    });
                }).end(requestBody);
            });
       };
     }); 
   });
 }
```

#### Run the mocha test:

`node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha` testFile

Comment: It looks to me like this is testing the http module, while the OP asked for a way to test the handler code without sending http requests.

Comment: Wow this is an old post here coming back...  I was showing how to make assertions on a http response callback object. This is not simply testing the node.JS http module but rather the actual response parameters (i.e. the data). The OP literally said "I am trying to test my send method" ... This is one way you can do it.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time back, but just in case anyone is looking for quick solution to this which *doesn't* involve setting up additional mock servers, here it goes.

You can use Jasmine's `spyOn` and `returnValue` to mock the response of Node's HTTP package. The Node.js doc [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) reads:

> A spy can **stub any function** and tracks calls to it and all arguments.

And [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.returnValue%3C/code%3E) it later reads:

> By chaining the spy with `and.returnValue`, all calls to the function will return a specific value.

So all you have to do is this:

```
spyOn(http, "request").and.returnValue(
    //Your mock response goes here.
);
```

I hope this helps others.