# How to compile jade template file to get string?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a view logic in my jade template file. How can I pass model in to jade and get html for further sending by email ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
var jade = require('jade'),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('template.jade', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
    var fn = jade.compile(data);
    var html = fn({name:'Oleg'});
    console.log(html);
});
```

Where `template.jade` is the path to your template. And it look like this:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= 'Hello world'
  body
    p Hello #{name}!
```

So you pass your model as input of the fn() function, and the output of it will be the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Hello world</title></head><body><p>Hello Oleg!</p></body></html>
```

Comment: You can use [app.render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render) to render a template to a string, as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403791/in-express-js-app-render-vs-res-render-whats-the-difference#answer-15404507) more recent answer.

Answer (score 13):

Also you can catch the string from render callback (express example)

```
exports.test1 = function(req, res){
  res.render('test1', { title: 'test1' }, function(err, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });

  res.send('wooo');
};
```

test1.jade

```
div
  = title
p hello world!
```

Answer (score 6):

Opening the template with `fs.readFile()` is no longer necessary. The Jade API includes the `compileFile()` method that compiles directly from a file.

```
var jade = require("jade");

var locals = {name: "Linus"},
    render = jade.compileFile('template.jade'),
    html   = render(locals);
```

The Jade API also includes the `renderFile()` method that directly returns an html string from a given file, making it even simpler.

```
var jade = require("jade");

var locals = {name: "Linus"},
    html   = jade.renderFile('template.jade', locals);
```

Comment: Correct. Here is a relevant question regarding how to check for errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283896/how-can-i-catch-a-rendering-error-missing-template-in-node-js-using-express-js/34709515#34709515

Comment: which jade version is that? my renderFile (v1.2.0) expects 3 arguments

Comment: @akcasoy These are the most current docs: http://jade-lang.com/api/. The `renderFile()` description is at the very bottom and shows 2 arguments are required.

Answer (score 1):

The answers all work for loading the jade template and compiling it to HTML using locals. However if you are sending HTML emails you need to be aware that most clients strip out all CSS classes. Use [Juice](https://www.npmjs.org/package/juice2) (or something like it) to apply all of the CSS classes inline.