# What's the difference between "app.render" and "res.render" in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Docs for [`app.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render):

> Render a view with a callback responding with the rendered string. This is the app-level variant of `res.render()`, and otherwise behaves the same way.

Docs for [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render):

> Render a view with a callback responding with the rendered string. When an error occurs `next(err)` is invoked internally. When a callback is provided both the possible error and rendered string are passed, and no automated response is performed.

How can I figure out when to use which one?

Answer (score 149):

Here are some differences:

1. You can call `app.render` on *root level* and `res.render` only *inside a route/middleware*.
2. `app.render` always returns the `html` *in the callback function*, whereas `res.render` does so only when you've specified the callback function as your third parameter. If you call `res.render` without the third parameter/callback function the rendered html is sent to the client with a status code of `200`.

   Take a look at the following examples.

   - **`app.render`**

     ```
     app.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'}, function(err, html) {
         console.log(html)
     });

     // logs the following string (from default index.jade)
     <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>res vs app render</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1>res vs app render</h1><p>Welcome to res vs app render</p></body></html>
     ```
   - **`res.render` without third parameter**

     ```
     app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
         res.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'})
     })

     // also renders index.jade but sends it to the client 
     // with status 200 and content-type text/html on GET /render
     ```
   - **`res.render` with third parameter**

     ```
     app.get('/render', function(req, res) {
         res.render('index', {title: 'res vs app render'}, function(err, html) {
             console.log(html);
             res.send('done');
         })
     })

     // logs the same as app.render and sends "done" to the client instead 
     // of the content of index.jade
     ```
3. [`res.render`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/2ccb6cf3507cac74716f87c6ee056e79f6afdc52/lib/response.js#L933) uses [`app.render`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/fea768dbccc036d883b03e38daebc38e5206031c/lib/application.js#L477) internally to render template files.
4. You can use the `render` functions to create *html emails*. Depending on your structure of your app, you might not always have acces to the `app` object.

   For example inside an external route:

   **`app.js`**

   ```
   var routes = require('routes');

   app.get('/mail', function(req, res) {
       // app object is available -> app.render
   })

   app.get('/sendmail', routes.sendmail);
   ```

   ---

   **`routes.js`**

   ```
   exports.sendmail = function(req, res) {
       // can't use app.render -> therefore res.render
   }
   ```

Comment: @zeMicro what about **cache** mechanism?? Is `app.render` uses it too?

Comment: How can get title Key value in client side? I am using HTML file (ejs)

Answer (score 24):

use `app.render` in scenarios where you need to render a view but not send it to a client via http. html emails springs to mind.

Answer (score 1):

along with these two variants, there is also `jade.renderFile` which generates html that need not be passed to the client.

usage-

```
var jade = require('jade');

exports.getJson = getJson;

function getJson(req, res) {
    var html = jade.renderFile('views/test.jade', {some:'json'});
    res.send({message: 'i sent json'});
}
```

`getJson()` is available as a route in app.js.