# Content doesn't render in root of webapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I'm building MERN stack app. I tried to use basic code to render something at localhost:3000. But content doesn't apear in root. When i changing path to '/something', content will render on that path. So, my question is: why content doesn't render on '/'?

**Edited.** In other words how to show '...' in localhost:3000?

Code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', {
            content: '...'
        })
    })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Read the answers on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403791/whats-the-difference-between-app-render-and-res-render-in-express-js

Comment: @DamienGold I get confused, because I've watch videos, where people were using the same code, and it worked.