# Can I render html in express without using res.render / return info to the user?

Tags: node.js, express, templates, handlebars.js

I want to render HTML the same way I render most other pages, with res.render(), which is set to use handlebars.

But I don't want to just return the HTML, I want to put the HTML into an object, along with some other info, and then return that.

I know I could load a new handlebars instance, but I don't want to do that as I need all the helpers and partials. Is there a way to render using the same instance of handlebars that res.render uses, but just returns me the HTML?

I want to do something like this:

```
router.get('/list', function(req, res, next) {
  Users((err, users)=>{
    if (err) console.log(err);

    var html = res.render('user-list', {
        layout: false,
        users: users,
    });

    res.json({
        html: html,
        otherInfo: otherInfo
    });
  });
});'
```

But obviously cant do that because res.render will start sending the HTML to the user.

Any tips?

edit: figured it out, just cant accept my own answer

Comment: FYI, you can accept your answer, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **req.app** to access the express instance, which has the method **render**, which will return the HTML. The function is asynchronous so you will need to provide a callback, not set it to a variable.

[app.render() docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render)

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by "stackers" works perfectly. However, my view to be rendered could not access the objects of the app. For example, I did not have access to my translations from the i18next package. Therefore, I would like to propose another solution [inspired by zemirco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15404507/5149302), res.render with third parameter:

```
res.render('viewName', {content: 'content to pass'}, function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        // do your error handling here
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.status(200).end(html);
        
        // When returning html in JSON-Object you might have to escape it
        res.json({
            html: html,
            otherInfo: otherInfo
        });

    }
})
```