# Express, check if a template exists

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way I can tell if a given template exists in express? Basically I want to create specific and fallback templates but don't want to contain that logic in the template itself.

```
if( res.templateExists( 'specific_page' ) ) {
  res.render( 'specific_page' );
} else {
  res.render( 'generic_page' );
}
```

The `specific_page` name is generatead at runtime based on the users device, language, etc.

*NOTE: I don't need to know how to do string localization within a template, that I already have. I'm looking for cases where the entire layout/template changes.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I catch a rendering error / missing template in node.js using express.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283896/how-can-i-catch-a-rendering-error-missing-template-in-node-js-using-express-js)

Answer (score 11):

You could use this:

```
res.render('specific_page', function(err, html) {
  if (err) {
    if (err.message.indexOf('Failed to lookup view') !== -1) {
      return res.render('generic_page');
    }
    throw err;
  }
  res.send(html);
});
```

This will distinguish between an error thrown because the template couldn't be found (in which case it will render `generic_page` instead), and any other errors that might occur (which are re-thrown). It's not entirely stable because it relies on the error message that's being thrown, but I don't think there's any other way of determining the type of error.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't let me distinguish between an error in the template and the template not existing. Thus I'd be uncertain if I should raise an alarm, fail a test, or otherwise.

Comment: I see that `err.message` is `template not found: <template-relative-path>` with nunjucks 3.0.0. Perhaps it got changed later from `Failed to lookup view` to this.

Comment: @trss given that the answer is more than 4 years old, I wouldn't be surprised :D

Comment: I'm using this to have a fallback template. It's disconcerting that there isn't a reliable way to achieve this. If there's any other way to have a fallback, do let me know.

Comment: @trss you could use `fs.exists(app.get('views') + '/your/template', ...)` or something similar

Comment: Wonder if nonexistence of the file would be cached by nunjucks and it would hook into fs changes to detect when the file comes into existence.

Comment: @trss no, and no, would be my guess. Template file resolving is done by Express anyway, not the templating engine.